# How to build Qt 5 from source with c++14 support

Tags: qt, c++14

I am attempting to build Qt 5.4.1 pulled from git with the -std=c++14 flag for gcc4.9. But I am not sure about how to properly pass the flag into the build process.

I have read that adding CONFIG += c++14 to a qt project file should work since Qt5.4, so I have added it into the qt.pro located in the top folder.

But Qt is still compiled with -std=c++0x (c++11).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you using *g++* or *clang++* to build the **Qt 5**, then go to `qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/common/g++-base.conf` or `qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/common/clang.conf` respectively and simply change the right hand side of `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX11 = -std=c++11` assignment to (for example) `-std=gnu++1z` (or to whatever you need).

To build **Qt 5** you have to run `qt5/configure` script with `-c++11` provided (and `-platform linux-clang-libc++` or `linux-clang` or `linux-g++` or whatever you need — the parameter is the `qt/qtbase/mkspecs/*/` directory name represented your platform).

Comment: I have modified `qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/common/g++-base.conf`, changed  `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX11` to `-std=c++14`, and then run:
`./configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests -no-gtkstyle -confirm-license`.
It compiled successfully with gcc 4.9.2, so the -c++11, or -platform flags weren't necessary in my case. Thanks!

Comment: @phcerdan I can conclude, that the platform automatically selected. If you have *g++* and *clang++* installed in your `${PATH}`, then one of them have priority higher then the other. In that case you would have to specify the `-platform` option explicitly.