# enable c++1y in qt (mingw)

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qmake, c++14

I'm trying ton enable `CONFIG += c++14` in qmake (using mingw), but I always get `-std=c++0x` in the makefiles generated. the only workaround I found is to add in my .pro file `QT_GCC_MAJOR_VERSION = 4` and `QT_GCC_MINOR_VERSION =` 9, then I get properly `-std=c++1y`. Those variables should be set automatically according to the compiler used, am I right ? What could make these variables not being set ?

The most simple pro file i can imagine also have this problem:

```
TARGET = testProj

TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG += c++14

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Comment: You may want to use `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++1y` instead, even if that doesn't really answer your question.

Comment: What version of Qt and MinGW/GCC are you using?  Bear in mind that the `CONFIG += c++14` switch is only available in QT 5.4 and C++14 is only partially supported in GCC >4.9.

Comment: I am using the latest qtsdk, so it is qt 5.4.1 and mingw 4.9.1. I get the same behaviour from qt creator and console

Comment: Post your `.pro` file.

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28607097/1430927

Comment: You can simply add `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX11 = -std=c++14` (to replace global one) to your `.pro` file and append `CONFIG += c++11` to the same.

Comment: @Orient Are you saying CONFIG += c++14 is useless ? the other stackoverflow question is about compiling qt, which does not apply in my case

Comment: @EricLemanissier Indeed, it is your case exactly. `mkspecs` configuration files used furhter, when you using compiled *Qt*.

Comment: @Orient maybe it's because I'm using mingw, but changing g++-base.conf does not have any impact on the makefiles generated. the file win32-g++\qmake.conf does, but a better portable solution would be to modify the c++14.prf file, so that it works as expected and have no impact when CONFIG += c++14 is not set. However these are just workarounds for a missing feature during compilation of qt with mingw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in fact a Qt bug which affects mingw : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44142

An easy workaround is to edit the file `mkspecs\features\c++14.prf` and comment out the line `greaterThan(QT_GCC_MAJOR_VERSION, 4)|greaterThan(QT_GCC_MINOR_VERSION, 7): \`